# In Google chart how to show data points dynamically?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Here i am trying to draw a line chart for selling price vs month for last three years data.
Data list is coming from database bases of current year, last year and last-to-last year.

so, i made a data array like below array from php code :

```
[
['January',  37.8, 80.8, 41.8],
['February',  30.9, 69.5, 32.4],
['March',  25.4,   57, 25.7],
['April',  11.7, 18.8, 10.5],
['May',  11.9, 17.6, 10.4],
['June',   8.8, 13.6,  7.7],
['July',   7.6, 12.3,  9.6],
['August',  12.3, 29.2, 10.6],
['September',  16.9, 42.9, 14.8],
['October', 12.8, 30.9, 11.6],
['November',  5.3,  7.9,  4.7],
['December',  6.6,  8.4,  5.2]
]
```

And then passing it to google chart draw function using dataJson parameter. see:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  let dataJson = '<?php echo $dataJson; ?>';
  var newData = JSON.parse((dataJson));

  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
  var  data="";
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(salesChart);

  function salesChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Months');
    data.addColumn('number', '2019');
    data.addColumn('number', '2018');
    data.addColumn('number', '2017');
    data.addRows(newData);
    var options = {
    'title' : 'All over Sales',
      hAxis: {
        title: 'Month'
      },
      vAxis: {
        title: 'Selling Price'
      },
      width: 900,
      height: 500,
      curveType: 'function'
    };
    var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('salesgraph'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
  }
  </script>
  <div id="salesgraph"></div>
```

Now, graph is ok. But the data points should be visible on graph with values. So please guide me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zph8B.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed :

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line','corechart']});
```

and

```
data.addColumn('string', 'Months');
  data.addColumn('number', '2019');
  data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'annotation'});
  data.addColumn('number', '2018');
  data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'annotation'});
  data.addColumn('number', '2017');
  data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'annotation'});
```

and

var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('salesgraph'));

and change php array like:

```
['January',  37.8,'37.8',  80.8,'80.8', 41.8,'41.8'],
```

[Click here to see result !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dU2Mu.png)

Answer (score 0):

everything seems ok in your code. the only thing missing is **pointSize** in options. so add pointSize with desired point size and you will be able to see the points.

e.g:`var options = {
    'title' : 'All over Sales',
      hAxis: {
        title: 'Month'
      },
      vAxis: {
        title: 'Selling Price'
      },
      width: 900,
      height: 500,
      curveType: 'function',
      pointSize: 10,
    };`

hope it will solve your issue

Comment: Thanks, But not fixed. Graph remain same after adding point size,  and also i want to show point with there values.

Comment: sorry for lately answer. I was testing your source code. found the problem and successfully run it. change google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']}) to google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': [ 'corechart','line'] }); and change var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('salesgraph')); to var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('salesgraph'));

Comment: I am going to add second answer with full solution

Answer (score 0):

Try below. You have to add annotations to show values with vaxis points.

```
[
['January',  37.8, 80.8, 41.8,41.8],
['February',  30.9, 69.5, 32.4,32.4],
['March',  25.4,   57, 25.7,25.7],
['April',  11.7, 18.8, 10.5,10.5],
['May',  11.9, 17.6, 10.4,10.4],
['June',   8.8, 13.6,  7.7,7.7],
['July',   7.6, 12.3,  9.6,9.6],
['August',  12.3, 29.2, 10.6,10.6],
['September',  16.9, 42.9, 14.8,14.8],
['October', 12.8, 30.9, 11.6,11.6],
['November',  5.3,  7.9,  4.7,4.7],
['December',  6.6,  8.4,  5.2,5.2]
] 


<script type="text/javascript">


  let dataJson = '<?php echo $dataJson; ?>';
  var newData = JSON.parse((dataJson));

  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
  var  data="";
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(salesChart);

  function salesChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Months');
    data.addColumn('number', '2019');
    data.addColumn('number', '2018');
    data.addColumn('number', '2017');
    data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'annotation'});
    data.addRows(newData);
    var options = {
    'title' : 'All over Sales',
      hAxis: {
        title: 'Month'
      },
      vAxis: {
        title: 'Selling Price'
      },
      width: 900,
      height: 500,
      curveType: 'function',
      pointSize: 5
    };
    var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('salesgraph'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
  }
  </script>
  <div id="salesgraph"></div>
```

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Row given with size different than 7 (the number of columns in the table).

Comment: Try it now. i modified the data set as well.